# How to get an array of current directory listing including file/directory name, last modified, and size in Java?

Tags: java

I know the code below will return the current files or directories in a directory:

```
import java.io.File;

public class test {

  File f = null;
  String[] paths;


     // create new file
     f = new File(".");

     // array of files and directory
     paths = f.list();

     // for each name in the path array
     for(String path:paths)
     {
        // prints filename and directory name
        System.out.println(path);
     }
}
```

but I need to return the results like below with file size, last date modified, and filename.  I am not seeing how to do this with the File class methods. Any help?

```
 424  May 27 14:09:03  MyCode$1.class
 535  May 27 14:09:03  MyCode$2.class
2489  May 27 14:09:03  MyCode.class
4391  May 27 14:08:57  MyCode.java
4323  May 26 14:48:17  MyCode.java~
 822  May 26 15:05:12  testcases
```

Comment: Did you look at the methods of the API? What methods do you think you should use? What methods don't you understand how to use? Show us that you have taken the time to read the API and ask a question about the methods that you don't understand.

Comment: Size = [`File#length`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length()), last modified = [`File#lastModified`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified()) in milliseconds since the unix epoch, wrap it in a `java.util.Date` and format as you need to, name = [`File#getName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Size = [`File#length`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length())
- Last modified = [`File#lastModified`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified()) in milliseconds since the unix epoch, use a `DateFormat` to format it
- Name = [`File#getName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName())

For example...

```
File f = new File(".");

File[] files = f.listFiles();

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH:mm:ss");

// for each name in the path array
for (File file : files) {

    System.out.printf("%4d %s %s%n", file.length(), df.format(file.lastModified()), file.getName());

}
```

Which outputs something like...

```
   0 Oct 21 16:05:28 build
3597 Oct 21 16:04:16 build.xml
  85 Oct 21 16:04:17 manifest.mf
4096 Oct 21 16:04:16 nbproject
   0 Oct 21 16:04:16 src
```

Comment: Good one Mad. One true answer.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Got tired of trying to nudge people to correct their answers...:P

Comment: @user3740517 Beware, `length` may be more the 4 characters long, you might want to play around with it a bit ;)